# How to setup tinymce 4 spellcheck for asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, orchardcms, tinymce-4

I'm trying to setup tinymce 4 spellcheck for Orchard CMS. Is there some asp.net mvc/web api server side spellchecker I can adapt to Orchard CMS?

Currently I found only https://github.com/fellowshiptech/TinyMCESpellcheck.NET but this project looks abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do spell check with Orchard CMS. See the following link
http://www.aspnetspell.com/MVCInstallation